# Quantifying impact of event/intervention on time series data

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

Just want to find out if there are some sort of statistical measures to quantify changes in time series data. Particularly in situations where there is some sort of impact that changes the time series data drastically at a certain time t = t1.  In this situation, the graph below shows ndvi (greenness of vegetation) which follows a seasonal pattern, which is affected drastically due to volcanic eruption. I want to find out if there is some sort of statistical measure/way to quantify this.
[image]

Comment: Did this drop happen inside one time step? If so, it is easier. You can calculate differences between successive timeseries points, get their variance/standard deviation, and then state that this sharp dive is like 10 standard deviations large.

Comment: Thanks for this. This curve is actuall fitted values (smoothed curve) from some ndvi data i recieved. It isnt through one time step but rather after volcanic eruption the ndvi values have dropped. I am noob at time series, so was wondering if there was a way to quantify this sort of change which i can implement.  Some sort of change detection in timeseries other than just visually observing it.

Comment: Can you use just Excel? Try forecast in it, based on triple exponetital smoothing. Points outside of prediction interval are suspicious.

Comment: I am using python for this. Yep, the drop seems quite large and the recovery of the vegetation doesn't seem gradual.

Comment: Then try triple exponential model (Holt Winters) with interval 99%. The drop must go outside of it.